# Is it right to think that all dependencies in a React-webpack web app package.json are dev dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, dependencies

I have a React-webpack web app (client side only - no API server) and was tidying up the package.json file and it occurred to me that *all* of the dependencies are dev dependencies as you do not run the React web app in production - you build it and distribute the built files.

Is this right?

Comment: Had to re-read this a few times.  It managed to get me thinking and my initial feeling is that I agree with you in the context of a simple app

Comment: Apologies if this question sounds like a bit like a stream of conciousness!

Answer (score 2):

React and possibly ReactDOM would be dependencies. Any additional libraries you're using that appear on the page would also be dependencies (example: [react-autosuggest](https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest)). Everything else would generally be a devDependency.

There's no great consensus on this yet (see [this webpack issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/520), for instance). Some folks want to do everything as a dependency, others as a devDependency, I'm sure you could make a case for bundled dependencies, etc. The solution I outlined above is a best practice that seems to work well. For example, if you're using a version range on a package, you likely wouldn't care about minor/patch version change to webpack, eslint, karma, mocha, etc. You'd most certainly care about even a patch level change to something like react, so it gets separated out into a much shorter dependency list. (Looking at one project, there seems to be a 4-5x difference between dependency and devDependency. It's much easier to spot the meaningful changes if you corral them into the dependency tree.)

Related: yarn [takes the approach](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/dependency-types) I outlined above.

Comment: But would the checked out project have any use whatsoever if I did a `npm i --production`?

Comment: Any utility libraries would fall into the _dependencies_ as well i.e. `Lodash`

Comment: There's no reason to `npm i --production` this project because it's a top level react application. It's likely the end of your npm dependency chain, unless you're doing something extremely creative.

Comment: But if there is no need for a production dependency install, aren't all the dependencies dev dependencies then?

Comment: Edited my answer to provide some additional background